# How to add line break in richtextarea field

Tags: email-template

I have a requirement to implement a user email signature in visualforce email template,and i have tried this code `{!$User.Email_Signature_Rich__c}` it's appering without line breaks in signature.How to add line break in rich text area field.
 [image]

Email_Signature_Rich__c is Richtextarea field.

E.g. it shows

```
Test, Queensland, AUS
```

i want to show like this

```
Test, 
Queensland, 
AUS


<messaging:emailTemplate subject=" Query Notification – DC: {!relatedTo.Distribution_Centre__r.DC_Number__c} - Vendor - {!relatedto.Vendor_Number__r.Vendor_Number__c} {!relatedto.Vendor_Number__r.Name} " recipientType="User" relatedToType="Case">

<messaging:htmlEmailBody >
<html>
      <body>
        <STYLE type="text/css">
          TH {font-size: 11px; font-face: arial;background: #CCCCCC;
               border-width: 0;  text-align: center } 
          TD  {font-size: 11px; font-face: verdana } 
          TABLE {border: solid #CCCCCC; border-width: 0}
          TR {border: solid #CCCCCC; border-width: 5}
        </STYLE>
        <font face="arial" size="2">

          <p>Hi {!recipient.name},</p>
          <p>The below DC Receiving Query has been received and requires action:</p>

<table colunm = "6" border = "5">
            <tr > 

               <th>PO Number(s)</th>
               <th> Buyer Name</th>
               <th> Event Number </th>
               <th> Container Number </th>
               <th> Number Pallets / Cartons </th>
               <th> PO Line Item </th>
               <th> Keycode </th>
               <th> Booking Date / Time</th>


            </tr>
            <apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.Big_W_Case_PO__r}">
              <tr>                
              <!--<td><c:Email_DC_Receiving thiscaseId="{!relatedTo.id}" /> </td>--> 
               <td>{!cx.PO__r.Name}</td>
                <td>{!cx.PO__r.Department_Team__r.Name}</td>
                <td>{!cx.PO__r.Event_Number__c}</td>
                <td>{!cx.PO__r.Container_Number__c}</td>                
                <td>{!cx.PO__r.Number_Pallets_Cartons__c}</td>
                <td><c:Email_DC_Receiving_PoLineItem thiscaseId="{!cx.id}" /> </td>
                  <td><c:Email_DC_Receiving_Keycode thiscaseId="{!cx.id}" /> </td>  

                <td><c:BIG_W_Locale_FormatDateTime date_Timevalue="{!cx.PO__r.Booking_Date_Time__c}"/></td>
              </tr>

            </apex:repeat>

            </table>                    



              <b> Kind Regards,</b><br/>
            <!--  {!$User.Email_Signature_Rich__c}-->
           <apex:outputField value="{!recipient.Email_Signature_Rich__c}"/>     
    </font>
      </body>
    </html>
</messaging:htmlEmailBody>


</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Comment: How have you stored in rich text field?Is it with line break?

Comment: @MohithKumar:  yes and i have updated the question with the Screenshot of the Rich text signature field.

Answer (score 1):

The solution would to use OutputField so that formatting stays rather than simple merge field

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="helo" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Case">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >
  <apex:outputField value="{!recipient.Email_Signature_Rich__c}"/>
</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.we tried your code which throws the following error. Could not resolve the entity from <apex:outputField> value binding '{!$User.Email_Signature_Rich__c}'. <apex:outputField> can only be used with SObjects, or objects that are Visualforce field component resolvable.

Comment: Are you not using Sobject?If yes then look into your data model to see how you can go from record to user .But output field is safest way to use this .

Comment: :sorry,i tried the following code now ,relatedto="Case"
<apex:outputfield value="{!relatedto.owner.Email_Signature_Rich__c}"/> 

following is the error message
Error: Could not resolve field 'Email_Signature_Rich__c' from <apex:outputField> value binding '{!relatedto.owner.Email_Signature_Rich__c}' in page 

How to display the user custom field(Email_Signature_Rich__c) in VF email template

Comment: try the above .I edited the answer and Tested Myself .Looks good now

Comment: hi mohith i tried ur code but it not working its show empty and add my email template code.

Comment: Check field level security and make sure your user has the signature data populated .Workks great for me

Comment: Where we can mention the particular user. For example if we have three user with three different signature then how can we take the user1 signature in email template? Can you please advice on this?

Comment: Based on which users signature you want create fields on the Record itself and copy the data via trigger or workflow .Thats the only work around .